# Azure DevOps - View number of changes per check-in or per day?

Tags: azure-devops

Is there an easy way to view the number of changes (number of files, number of lines, number of warnings etc.) made per check-in or per day?

I'm trying to draw a report that can give me a feel for the amount of work done per check-in/day, so I'm looking for a consolidated listing or chart without manually digging into each change set.

Comment: Do you use TFVC or Git?

Comment: Not related to resolving your question, but [Are there known valid uses of SLOC to measure productivity?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/360979/are-there-known-valid-uses-of-sloc-to-measure-productivity)

Comment: @Matt Yes, there are. See McConnell "Rapid Development" and/or "Code Complete". Although it is very trendy to jump up and down and whine about how SLOC is not a good measure of productivity, it turns out its pretty good when averaged out over large numbers. The other more accurate methods require a lot more effort and a lot more measuring. And when you find yourself without any good measurements SLOC is always easily available. Although not a good indication of quality it does give an indication of "how much work" may have been "spent".

Comment: @Vernou Mostly TFVC, but some Git

Comment: Where you want to draw the report? The Dashboard tab under OverView?

Comment: Dashboard would be nice, but anywhere if it works

Comment: Azure Devops supports one official widget called [Code Tile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#code-tile), it can be used to display recent changes within one git repo. But to display the numbers of changes per check-in and per day, as I know there's no such widget. You can search the [Extension marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/azuredevops) to check whether there's such third-party extension.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using Azure DevOps RestApi's. Just to give you an example we are generating report to find the number of PR's raised. Similarly you can use this script and customize the same to identify the number of checkin's.

```
 #+++Declaring all the parameters+++
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "https://dev.azure.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   [string]$project = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   [string]$token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   [string]$Filename = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\xxxxxx.csv'
)

#++PassingToken as Base 64++
$auth = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$token)))

#++Generating Pull Request Base URL++
$pullRequestURL = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/git/pullrequests?searchCriteria.status=all&&api-version=5.1"

#++Passing Respone in variable++           
$pullRequest = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $pullRequestURL -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $auth)}).value

#++Displaying result on screen( this step can be avoided )++
Write-Output $pullRequest
#++Counting Active vs Completed Request++
Write-host "Count of active pull request:" ($pullRequest | where({$_.status -eq 'active'})).count
Write-host "Count of completed pull request:" ($pullRequest | where({$_.status -eq 'completed'})).count

#++Temporary Object to store varaible values"
$output = @()
Write-Output $output

#++Extracting Values and storing in Object++
foreach ($request in $pullRequest) {
    $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "RepositoryName" = $request.repository.name
                                  "Status" = $request.status
                                  "PullRequestId" = $request.pullRequestId
                                  "SourceBranch" = $request.sourceRefName
                                  "TargetBranch" = $request.targetRefName
                                  "CreatedBy" = $request.createdBy.displayName
                                  "Reviewers" = $request.reviewers.displayName
                                  "CreatedDate" = $request.creationDate
                                  "ClosedDate" = $request.closedDate
                                  "MergeStrategy" = $request.completionOptions.mergeStrategy
        }
                                $output += $customObject
                                }
#++Generating excel out of Object++                    
$output | Select `
            RepositoryName,
                                                Status,
                                                PullRequestId,
                                                SourceBranch,
                                                TargetBranch,
                                                CreatedBy,
            Reviewers,
                                                CreatedDate,
                                                ClosedDate,
                                                MergeStrategy | export-csv -Path $Filename -NoTypeInformation
```

Also, there is an extension available to view contribution done by users

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.contributions